# Redirect 301 with regular expressions to new url with different numeration

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I moved my system forum and I need some redirections. Is difficult for me redirect this urls.

```
website.com/folder1/123456-name-of-article
website.com/folder1/name-of-article-r654321
```

You can view this changes:

1. Old name article have a number before: number-name
2. New name article is the same but have othernumber and letter "r" at the end: name-rnumber

**Add NEW data**
An example of URL for redirect:

Original URL:
https://www.website.com/folder/2087-name-of-the-article

Source URL
https://www.website.com/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/

Comment: Your new shown sample URLs are totally different from your initial question, please don't change the requirement, it will be better to let the old question be there and you could open a nee question, looks like they are totally different, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution(Generic one, where its not checking if url starts from folder1):*** Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w-]+)/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])-(.*)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%8-r%7%6%5%4%3%2 [R=301,L]
```

OR without using RewriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])-(.*)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$8-r$7$6$5$4$3$2 [R=301,L]
```

When I test above rules with link `http://localhost/folder1/123456-name-of-article` it rewrites in backend to `http://localhost/folder1/name-of-article-r654321`.

---

---

***2nd solution(Where it checks uri starts from folder1):*** Above Rules are Generic ones, in case you want to check if URI starts specifically from `folder1` then try following ones, make sure either above OR following rules are only in your .htaccess file at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1)/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])-(.*)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%8-r%7%6%5%4%3%2 [R=301,L]
```

OR without RewriteCond in only single RewriteRule try:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(folder1)/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])-(.*)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$8-r$7$6$5$4$3$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 A clarification about my urls. When I put the number 123456 it is any number and when I put 7654321 it is also any number, but different from the previous one.

Comment: @juanma, sure I have not hard coded the number on my solutions. Is length is fixed or like any range in it? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: @juanma you do not answer to  RavinderSingh13 question in his remark above, 
is his solution right for you?

Comment: Sorry @bruno, I still couldn't test it. I will put the information when I do.

Comment: Sorry @RavinderSingh13. Doesn´t work. Hothing happens. I add more details to the questions.

Comment: @juanma, Your new shown sample URLs are totally different from your initial question, please don't change the requirement, it will be better to let the old question be there and you could open a nee question, looks like they are totally different, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 Sorry for my bad english. I will open new question.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499517/redirect-301-with-regular-expresions-to-other-url-with-similar-numeration