# Redirect 301 with regular expresions to other URL with similar numeration

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I migrated my articles in website, and the CMS system transform de URLs.

I need to redirect URLs similar to:

**Example, Case 1.** Same article name and different number at the end of URL:

Original URL: https://www.website.com/folder/2087-name-of-the-article

Source URL https://www.website.com/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/

**Example, Case 2.** Same article name and different number at the end of URL, but with other subfolder:

Original URL: https://www.website.com/folder/2087-name-of-the-article

Source URL https://www.website.com/folder0/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. In case you want to redirect(change URL in browser too) then add `R=301` with `L` flag in both the rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^folder/name-of-the-article-r929/?$ folder/2087-name-of-the-article [L]
RewriteRule ^folder0/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/?$ folder/2087-name-of-the-article [L]
```

This considers you want to rewrite `http://localhost:80/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/` to `http://localhost:80/folder/2087-name-of-the-article`

AND `http://localhost:80/folder0/folder/name-of-the-article-r929/` TO `http://localhost:80/folder/2087-name-of-the-article`.

Where `localhost` could be your domain name.